# FCM Send a batch of messages (device groups)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to send a different message for each group of devices. To not send message by message I want to use the batch option. Is it possible for groups? ([send batch messages doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages))

Example:

```
const messages = [];

messages.push({
  notification: { title: 'notf. Group 01', body: '...'},  // Message for group 01
  token: notification_key,  // Group key 01
});

messages.push({
  notification: { title: 'notf. Group 02', body: '...'},  // Message for group 02
  token: notification_key,   // Group key 02
});

.
.
.

admin.messaging().sendAll(messages)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.successCount + ' messages were sent successfully');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) device group messaging is supported via the legacy XMPP or HTTP protocols or the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js based on the legacy protocols.

As I understand, in order to [send a batch of messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging#type-aliases) the registration token, topic or a condition that specifies the target topics must be specified and then send the whole `messages[]` array by passing it as an argument to the [sendAll()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendall) method. Note that notification keys are not included to the [message type aliases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging#type-aliases_1).

In order to send messages to a [device group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#adminSDK-legacy-send-methods), the notification key is passed as an argument to the [sendToDeviceGroup()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendtodevicegroup) method. Looking again at the [sendAll()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendall) method that is used to send batches of messages, it doesn't have a parameter to take notification key as an input.

Hope you find the above helpful.